# Freeform Pro Composer - Dynamic Recipients always uses default notification template

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I am wondering how I can specify the notification template for a form created using the composer feature which has dynamic recipients. When the form is sent to them it always uses the default template. I have tried adding it to the tag in the template

```
{exp:freeform:composer parse="inward"
    form_id="{exp:stash:get name='petition_id' trim='yes'}"
    return="act-now/thank-you"
    recipient_user_template="petition_template"
}
```

But according to the documentation this is not even a parameter of the composer tag but just of the form tag. I have tried setting the user notification template in the settings of the actual form in the control panel but nothing seems to change it from the default.

Freeform Pro 4.2.2 on EE 2.9.2

Comment: `{exp:freeform:form}` parameters should work in `{exp:freeform:composer}` as well. Do you have a dynamic recipients field in your Composer form in the CP? Do you have a notification template set up in the CP called `petition_template`?

Comment: Yes on both accounts. I just noticed the line in the documentation that says in addition to all the parameters in freeform:form.... that will help with some other things I need to do. Is recipient_user_template the correct parameter to use?

Comment: Ok I have it sort of. When I originally created the dynamic recipients in the composer form I hadn't created the notification template and so it was set to default. I thought the parameter should override what that setting was but it doesn't. Going and changing the setting in the composer form sends it to the right notification template. This will work for my purposes but I am surprised the parameter doesn't override what is set in the form.